# UIPageControl indicator dot does not change when the page changes

Tags: ios, ios7, uipagecontrol

I'm having an issue with the `UIPagecotrol`. It's not activating in the simulator. The dots will not change to the next view.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    for (NSUInteger i =0; i < [self.childViewControllers count]; i++) {
        [self loadScrollViewWithPage:i];
    }

    self.pageControl.currentPage = 0;
    _page = 0;
    [self.pageControl setNumberOfPages:[self.childViewControllers count]];

    UIViewController *viewController = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:self.pageControl.currentPage];
    if (viewController.view.superview != nil) {
        [viewController viewWillAppear:animated];

    }

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width * [self.childViewControllers count], scrollView.frame.size.height);
}

- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page {
    if (page < -0)
        return;
    if (page >= [self.childViewControllers count])
        return;

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    UIViewController *controller = [self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if (controller == nil) {
        return;
    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil) {
        CGRect frame = self.scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:controller.view];
    }
}


// At the begin of scroll dragging, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    _pageControlUsed = NO;
}

// At the end of scroll animation, reset the boolean used when scrolls originate from the UIPageControl
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    _pageControlUsed = NO;
}

- (IBAction)changePage:(id)sender; {

}
```

SOURCE CODE HERE: https://mega.co.nz/#F!0EkBQbTK!bKjEwFf7BQsUx0YGtoHehw

Just download in zip and run in Xcode. Notice that the `UIPageControl` won't shift with current page.

Answer (score 0):

You might to take a look at this blog article: http://mobileappdev.learningtree.com/2012/12/18/paging-with-collection-views-part-2/ ... I just used it to setup my UIPageControl element, and it works fine. You might have to adapt it a bit for your specific needs...